# Apply FuzzyLogic on a very large file

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

Hi I am trying to apply fuzzylogic to compare strings from two different files. This code works fine for smaller datasets. But I am facing memory issues when I try to apply the same code on a large dataset. When I run the code it says `Low memory Unable to create 6.6GB array`.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import difflib
import pandas as pd

df_To_beMatched = pd.read_excel('Vendor_file.xlsx', encoding='utf-8', usecols=["VENDOR_NAME"])
df_To_beMatched['VENDOR_NAME'] = df_To_beMatched['VENDOR_NAME'].fillna('')
original_list = df_To_beMatched['VENDOR_NAME'].tolist()
# print(original_list)

df_exceptionlist = pd.read_excel('Exceptionfile.xlsx', encoding='utf-8', usecols=["Entity_Name"])
df_exceptionlist['Entity_Name'] = df_exceptionlist['Entity_Name'].fillna('')
exception_list = df_exceptionlist['Entity_Name'].tolist()

# print(exception_list)

result = []
result_difflib = []
for exp in exception_list:
    to_delete = exp
    for orig in original_list:
        original = orig
        # print(to_delete, original)
        ratio = fuzz.ratio(to_delete, original)
        token = fuzz.token_set_ratio(to_delete, original)
        partial_ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(to_delete, original)
        # print(ratio, to_delete, original)
        if ratio > 75 and token > 75 and partial_ratio > 85:
            print(ratio, to_delete, original)
            result.append({'Entity_Name': to_delete, 'VENDOR_NAME': original, 'Ratio': ratio, 'Token': token,
                           'Status': 'Match'})
            break

    difflib_result = difflib.get_close_matches(to_delete, original_list)
    matches = "^".join(difflib_result)
    result_difflib.append({'Entity_Name': to_delete, 'Matches': matches})

    fuzzy_df = pd.DataFrame(result)

    fuzzy_df.to_csv('FuzzyLogic_Results.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what kinds of memory issues are occurring, so that the chances that someone will answer your question will increase?

Comment: Low memory Unable to create 6.6GB array is the error message I am getting.

Comment: I have added the information into the question body. However, I have noticed that your question has already been answered on Data Science Stack Exchange.